# How to get box-shadow color of a element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, colors, rgb

All is in the question i have tried this : `$('#my-div').css('box-shadow');` but it returns something like : `rgb(25,65,588) 10px 10px 10px`. How to get only the color ?

Comment: You need a regex. Be careful: if the browser doesn't support `box-shadow`, it will always return **undefined**

Comment: Right. I didn't notice that it returns the length also. I will incorporate that into my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will get the rgb or rgba expression

```
$('#my-div').css('box-shadow').replace(/^.*(rgba?\([^)]+\)).*$/,'$1')
```

Then you can use a converter to get the hexadicimal value

Comment: Thanks and can you give me the regex which will output me only 25,65,588 (without "rgb()" and ")") Thanks !

Comment: sure ... `.replace(/^.*rgba?\(([^)]+)\).*$/,'$1')`